# Reduce the size of an odt file

Tags: libreoffice, odt

Sorry if this is not the right forum in the frame. 
I reused a MS Word template to create a document with LibreOffice. The final output was a huge file, as lots of MS Windows fonts were integrated into the odt document. I unzipped to odt document, deleted the unused fonts. Now how can I compress the folder again to get my odt file back ?

Answer (score 2):

> Now how can I compress the folder again to get my odt file back ?

Zip it. When you enter the unzipped directory you can do

```
zip -r ../{filename}.odt
```

where {filename} is the name you want it to be and it will recreate your .odt; hopefully with a smaller size.

---

Extra comment:

The "mimetype" file should be 1st in the archive (though OO does not care about it other software might). You can force that by doing

```
zip -r ../{filename}.odt mimetype .
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I typed and the error message I got: 

root@m193530:/home/kalzi01/Documents/Projets/Sondage2017/PortraitLL_AdminPublique-V0.7.odt_FILES# zip -r ../Portraitv07Compresse.odt

zip error: Nothing to do! (../Portraitv07Compresse.odt)

Comment: Is there anything in the directory?

Comment: Yes, all the unzipped folders and files, which is the result of the extraction of any odf file.  Actually, it turned to be a LibreOffice matter. Here is what I did (I ended up finding the solution"): 

In LibreOffice Writer, I opened the file, went to file, properties, clicked on fonts tab and unchecked the box about fonts embedding. The size went from 9.3 MB down to 243K!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh big reduction :D Good you got it fixed.